# Microsoft Access 2010 LIKE clause character range (e.g., "[a-z]"]) not working

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

I am developing a custom ODBC driver to which I link using external ODBC data source from Microsoft Access 2010.  I issue the following query:

```
SELECT column_name from table_name where column_name like '[S-T]%';
```

Access seems to cut off the WHERE clause before submitting it to the ODBC driver manager.  When I enable tracing through the ODBC Data Source Administrator, the log shows

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name
```

When I remove the '[S-T]', the query works fine.  Also, the same query causing trouble in Access works fine when I run it under ODBC Test (MDAC 2.8 testing tool).

Any idea why Access might be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I asked the same question on the Office Dev Center forum and learned how to do a Pass-Through query to "bypass" Access' attempt to optimize my query.  Rather than repeating it all here, here is the link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f105538b-2e6a-42df-baf2-598f85277aba/microsoft-access-2010-cutting-off-where-clause-with-like-st?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 0):

The Wildcard symbol for Access is the asterisks.

Comment: Because this is correct, you should state the answer with more confidence and remove the "?".  You could also show the pattern that would make the query work.  Otherwise, this is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same results when I use an asterisk.  You can actually use either '*' or '%'.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just wasn't sure and I don't have anything at my fingertips to test if the % wildcard did or did not work in access.
ROGERSTOLLER I'll try and think about what the issue could be.